# How to vertically center elements in the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a React app and I want to build a navigation bar. However, I can't align the elements in the nav bar in the middle.
You can see it in the image below:
[image]

I've tried to add: `margin-bottom: 30px` but nothing worked:

Here is my react code:

```
return (
    <>
        <div className='home-bar'>
            <div className="home-bar-links">
                <p>Mathly</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </>
);
```

and here is my css:

```
.home {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.home-bar {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 7vh;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    background-color: #D9B99B;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.home-bar-links {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Why `flex-direction: row-reverse;`?

Comment: Because I want the items to go from left to right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vertical alignment, just add `align-items: center;` to your home-bar CSS. Then remove `margin-bottom: 150px;` from your home-bar-links CSS, like so:

```css
.home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.home-bar {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 7vh;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #D9B99B;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home-bar-links {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  /* margin-bottom: 150px; */
}
```

```html
<div class='home-bar'>
  <div class="home-bar-links">
    <p>Mathly</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `align-items` controls the alignment of items on the cross axis (which, **in this case**, is the vertical axis, as your flex-direction is set to **row**, which makes the horizontal axis the main axis).